# Complex numbers question (finding the Im)

Tags: complex-numbers

So I've been wrestling with this for about an hour and am still not sure how to solve it.

The task is to find the **Im** part of the complex number (it has to be as short as possible, or else it'd be easy):

$$\frac{1}{(z^2 + zi)}$$

for $z=(\sqrt{2}-i)/3$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

I've first tried to replace $z$ but it didn't turn out well as I get very big numbers and it's really hard to keep track of everything (it doesn't seem like the task I normally get, which solves easier, that's why I had decided to quit with that way.)

I've also tried multiplying the first expression with

$$\frac{z^2  - zi}{z^2 -zi}$$

This way I get the solution  which is pretty small comparing to the first, includes big numbers, but seems like a good one. So I want to ask if there is another way of solving this and what is the correct solution and the way you got it.

I hope someone answers, as I really want to know how to solve this kind of expression.

EDIT: It has been solved in the first comment.

Comment: Try computing $z^2 + iz = z(z+i)$ first. That simplifies things a lot here.

Comment: I've seen that but didn't try that way... thought it was too easy, ok, I'll try.

Comment: It worked. I don't know what I was thinking. It's usually harder than that and prof. said it's the one to 'think about' ... I feel ashamed.